# ElasticSearch Index API SLOW

Tags: elasticsearch

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Node node = nodeBuilder().clusterName("somethingstupid").client(true).node();
        Client client = node.client();

            String json = 
                    "{\"user\":\"kimchy\"," +
                    "\"postDate\":\"2013-01-30\"," +
                    "\"message\":\"trying out Elastic Search\"}";              

            IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("testindex", "article")
                    .setSource(json)
                    .execute()
                    .actionGet();

    }
```

Why does it take 9 -12 seconds to index this in eclipse?

Centosx64 6.4, ES 0.90.7, 2GB ram, nothing else running, Sysmon shows using 3% cpu and 800MB RAM AT PEAK (DURING INDEX).

EXAMPLE THREAD:

```
public class TestPostMethod2 implements Runnable{
    public static Node node = nodeBuilder().clusterName("somethingstupid").client(true).node();
    public static Client client = node.client();

    public void run() {
        String json = 
                "{\"user\":\"kimchY\"," +
                "\"postDate\":\"2016-01-30\"," +
                "\"message\":\"trying out Elastic Search\"}";              

        IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("testindex", "article")
                .setSource(json)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        (new Thread(new TestPostMethod2())).start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Does that time also include connecting to the cluster?

Comment: Um. Not sure. My apologies. What does that mean? I believe the above connects to the cluster indexes a document and then closes the connection. [sorry for my ignorance here]

Comment: The Cluster 'somethingstupid' is already running and the index already exists with documents of the same type and same fields, so it should be warm -- and still 9-12 seconds to index it with java client. Curl is Instant....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a full elasticsearch node takes time.
In a real project, once you get a Client, you just have to share it within all threads.

The index part should be fast.

If you want to index more docs, consider using the Bulk API.

Comment: is this more in line of what you are referring to (Example Thread)? It still takes the same time. I want to index 1 document at a time so bulk doesn't look right for me.

Comment: So you will pay the price of launching a Node at first (use a Factory to build your Node instance). Then for future injections, reuse the same node instance and directly index a doc. It will be fast. Note that TransportClient will be faster to start than NodeClient.

Comment: Can you point me to where I can learn to build with a Factory? The only thing I can think of is building a Servlet to keep the node in memory waiting for connections? BTW- thank you for your time! Im sorry Im slow at this understanding...

Comment: Building a Node instance once and wait for connections is perfectly fine. If you are using Spring, you can look at https://github.com/dadoonet/spring-elasticsearch